# How to add WireGuard container to internal Docker network to add internet connectivity?

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, wireguard, docker-compose

I have two Docker networks:

- `public` which is a normal `bridge` network with access to the host upstream network
- `private` which is a `bridge`, `internal: true` and hosts a fleet of containers

```
networks:
  public:
    driver: bridge
  private:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.22.0.1
```

I want to isolate my fleet of containers from the host upstream network, so that's why I put them into an internal network. However, these hosts still need internet access, which I want to provide via WireGuard to a public VPN service. So I deployed `lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest` container into both the `public` and `private` networks, with a static IP in the `private` network.

Additionally, I developed a small `sh` script for the `private` containers to modify the route table (requires `NET_ADMIN` capability):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Get IP address of `wireguard` container
wireguard_ip=$(getent hosts wireguard | awk '{ print $1 }')

# Update route table
ip route del default
ip route add default via $wireguard_ip
```

So now my `private` containers send all their traffic to the `wireguard` container. However, the containers still cannot reach internet. This is my `wg0.conf`:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = herpderp
Address = 10.x.x.x/32
DNS = 10.x.x.x
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg+ -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg+ -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = herpderp
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = ip:port
```

I assume what's left to do is additional networking config to be done in the `PostUp` and `PreDown`, which I am not familiar with enough to do at this moment.

The `public` network is auto-generated by Docker Compose, and currently has this random CIDR: `172.29.0.0/16`.

The `private` network CIDR is fixed at `172.22.0.0/24`

Using terminal in the wireguard container, I can see there are 3 interfaces - `eth0`, `eth1` and `wg0`. It's not clear how Docker decides which of the `private`/`public` networks becomes `eth0` or `eth1`, but it looks like the `public` network becomes `eth0` and `private` network `eth1` consistently (again the algorithm is not clear to me, please tell me if you know it).

What additional config do I need to do (particularly in `wg0.conf`) to add internet connectivity to the containers in `private` network?

I use the Docker Desktop for Mac v4.16.2, and Docker Compose.